# Does Microsoft visual studio 2010 support c99?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c99

I would like to know if Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 supports C99. If not, how can I use the standard types like `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio support for new C / C++ standards?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146381/visual-studio-support-for-new-c-c-standards)

Comment: That's the 2008 edition, so not an exact duplicate.

Comment: http://herbsutter.com/2012/05/03/reader-qa-what-about-vc-and-c99/ pretty much says everything there is to say on the subject.

Comment: Looks like we're going to have [C99 library support in Visual Studio **2013**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Visual Studio 2010 does not support C99.  To use types from stdint.h, you will have to use a typedef.  A cross-platform way to do this would be:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
typedef signed short int16_t
#else
#include <stdint.h>
#endif
```

See also this this question:
[Visual Studio support for new C / C++ standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146381/visual-studio-support-for-new-c-c-standards)

Comment: What about the printing factor I use? In C99 **zd** works fine for both **32 bit and 64 bit** environment.

Comment: Sorry, what is a "printing factor" and what is a "zd"?

Comment: **%zd** print factor for **intptr_t** as **%d** for **int**

Comment: Just make sure to pick the real type, rather than the "signed short" placeholder in the example.

Comment: @thetna That's not called a "printing factor", it's called a "conversion specifier".

Comment: It doesn't implement all of C99, but MSVC 2010 *does* have intptr_t: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/323b6b3k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 13):

Visual Studio 2010 does not support C99 syntax. `stdint.h` is a very common file in all C/C++ compilers, though, which does exist in a Visual C++ 10.0 installation, included with the [Windows SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/%20Windows%20SDK) (regardless of the version of Visual Studio that you use).

stdint.h can be found in:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\

This file does provide a typedef for `intptr_t`. Feel free to use it in any C or C++ project you like.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft C does not support C99.  However, MSVC 16 (what's provided with Visual Studio 2010) implements a good portion of the upcoming C++0x standard. C++0x is incorporating some of the headers from C99, such as `stdint.h` and `inttypes.h` - that's why you get some tidbits of C99 with MSVC 16.

Be thankful for small things (I wish MSVC supported a bit more of C99 when compiling straight C files).