# C: free memory allocated in c

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

suppose i have a struct:

```
typedef struct{
    char *ID;
    char *name;
    float price;
    int quantity;
} Generic_Properties;
```

now if i have used malloc to allocate space in the heap for it and saved the address in a pointer, lets call him `p1`. now i want to free that specific memory block, is it enough to just declare `free(p1)`:

```
free(p1);
```

or do i need to separately free ID and name pointers, because I used malloc to allocated space for the string they're pointing to?

Comment: Everything you `malloc` you need to `free`.

Comment: As @JoachimPileborg said. Plus a note: you usually need to `free` ID and name before you `free` the properties structure (unless you keep a copy of those pointer somwhere), because the `ID` and `name` member variables are not valid once you freed the structure they belong to.

Answer (score 10):

The rule is, `malloc` and `free` should come in pair. Free everything thing that is `malloc`ed exactly once.

```
char name[] = "some_name";
Generic_Properties *p1 = malloc(...);  /* 1 */
p1->ID = malloc(...); /* 2 */
p1->name = name;
...
...
/* free(p1->name); Don't do this, p1->name was not allocated with malloc*/
free(p1->ID);  /* 2' */
free(p1); /* 1' */
/* if(p1 && p1->name[0] == '?') {} don't dereference p1 after it is freed. It is dangling now */
...
...
/* free(p1); don't free p1 again as it is already freed and is dangling. */
p1 = NULL;
free(p1); /* OK */
```

Answer (score 2):

> or do i need to separately free ID and name pointers, because I used
>   malloc to allocated space for the string they're pointing to?

As pointed out by Mohit Jain, every call to `malloc` must be followed by a `free` call, but in this case (see comments bellow) nothing prevents you to reserve space for everything in a single call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    char *ID;
    char *name;
    float price;
    int quantity;
} Generic_Properties;

int main(void)
{
    Generic_Properties *x = malloc(sizeof(*x) + 100);
    x->ID = (char *)(x + 1);
    x->name = x->ID + 50;

    strcpy(x->ID, "00001");
    strcpy(x->name, "David");
    printf("%s %s\n", x->ID, x->name);
    free(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is really wise :)

Comment: In a general case, there can be alignment problems here, though (say, if `ID` weren't a `char*` but a `long long*` instead).

Comment: @TimČas, I also thought that, but [take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19768186/1606345)

Comment: @AlterMann: His rationale is only for that very specific struct containing `int*, int*` -- where the alignment of `int*` is (in most relevant archs) at least 4 bytes, and the same holds for `int`. In other words, the alignment is guaranteed to be proper *in that specific case*. Replace `int*` with a `long long*` and you're in trouble: Say, in x86, `long long` has (say) 8-byte alignment while `T*` is still 4-byte.

Comment: TimČas, sorry, I don't get you, maybe I am wrong but `sizeof` takes care of this problem (padding/alignment), look at the comments in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12883482/1606345)

Comment: @AlterMann: I did. As I said, that's the exact problem. Consider this case in x86 (32-bit pointers, 64-bit long long): `struct Foo { long long* ptr; }`. `sizeof(Foo) == 4`, and yet, `alignof(long long) == 8`.

Comment: @TimČas, I still don't get you, I consider your case (x86 (32-bit pointers, 64-bit long long): `sizeof(Foo) == 4`, and yet, `alignof(long long) == 8`): see it on [ideone](https://ideone.com/vwkKNB), where is the problem?

Comment: @AlterMann: "Works in one specific implementation on one specific computer" does not mean it's okay. I could write code like `*(int*)0x12345678 = 5;`, and it might work by coincidence; doesn't make it okay. And yes, your example works in x86, but it's *SLOW*. Now consider the same example in ARM, where unaligned reads or writes result in a bus error. `alignof(long long) == 8`, and yet it's only aligned to a multiple of `4`.

Comment: @TimČas, I'm not saying you're wrong (in fact you are probably right), but  `malloc(sizeof(*x) + sizeof(long long));` must return an address properly aligned for both `struct` and `long long`, isn't it?

Comment: @AlterMann: Yes. But when you add `sizeof(Foo)` to that address (4), it is no longer properly aligned. In other words, `malloc(...)` is aligned, `malloc(...)+x` is not (well, not necesarilly anyways).

Comment: @TimČas, thanks, now I understand, the [C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html) is confirming what you are saying: `However, piggybacking a second region onto a single malloc call like this is only portable if the second region is to be treated as an array of char. For any larger type, alignment (see questions 2.12 and 16.7) becomes significant and would have to be preserved. `

Answer (score 1):

A more object-oriented way of handling this sort of structure is to define functions for both allocating and freeing such structures.

*(Improved version of this code)*

```
// Allocate a GP object
Generic_Properties * create_GP()
{
    Generic_Properties *  p;

    p = malloc(sizeof(Generic_Properties));
    memset(p, 0, sizeof(*p));
    return p;
}

// Deallocate a GP object
void free_GP(Generic_Properties *p)
{
    if (p == NULL)
        return;

    free(p->ID);
    p->ID = NULL;

    free(p->name);
    p->name = NULL;

    free(p);
}
```

**Addendum**

If you want to combine this approach with [@Alter Mann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1606345/alter-mann)'s approach, you can do something like this:

```
// Allocate a GP object
Generic_Properties * create_GP2(const char *id, const char *name)
{
    size_t                idLen;
    size_t                nameLen;
    Generic_Properties *  p;

    // Reserve space for GP, GP.ID, and GP.name
    //  all in one malloc'd block
    idLen = strlen(id) + 1;
    nameLen = strlen(name) + 1;
    p = malloc(sizeof(Generic_Properties) + idLen + nameLen);
    memset(p, 0, sizeof(*p));

    // Save the ID
    p->ID = (char *)p + sizeof(Generic_Properties);
    memcpy(p->ID, id, idLen);

    // Save the name
    p->name = p->ID + idLen;
    memcpy(p->name, name, nameLen);
    return p;
}

// Deallocate a GP object
void free_GP2(Generic_Properties *p)
{
    free(p);
}
```

Comment: You don't need `if (p->ID != NULL)` conditions. It is perfectly fine to do `free(NULL)`

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten that feature of `free()`. I have edited my code above to be an improved version accordingly.