# convert a string to hex integer in C

Tags: c, type-conversion

I have the following C string

```
"72e4247d3c91f424c62d909d7c1553a5"
```

It consists of 32 hex digits. It is an array with 4 integers in hex. How can I get back the numbers in form of integers from this array?

Comment: 32 "digits", comprising only one number. As to how you can get them back -- do you have the code that did the initial conversion? Just reverse it. Most likely, take 8 digits at a time and convert each to its integer representation, perhaps using sscanf().

Comment: There are easily a dozen ways to convert character hex into binary.  (But do you really have character hex, or is that just a hex dump of the binary value of the string?)

Comment: @Hot Licks, it is really number. i turned it with sprintf and now i want to take back the initial value. but unfortunately i cannot do it.

Comment: That was clear as mud.  First off you need to understand the difference between a character string which contains characters 0-F representing a hex value, vs a character string containing almost anything but "dumped" in hex.  Do you know the difference?

Comment: i think so. correct me if i am wrong. i have arrays with 4 numbers, which when i try to print them with printf("%02x", ((unsigned char*)mdContext)[i]) i=[0,16], i get my wanted number with 32 digits. so is this on hex or not??

Comment: I'm puzzled.  If you created the string that way, why not just reference mdContext and fetch your data from it?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to parse the four 32-bit/8 hex digit chunks separately. The easiest way to do that is

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void parse_hex4(char const *str, uint32_t num[4])
{
    char buf[9];  // 8 hex digits + NUL

    buf[8] = '\0';
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        memcpy(buf, str + i * 8, 8);
        num[i] = strtoul(buf, NULL, 16);
    }
}
```

This assumes `str` is zero-padded to be exactly 32 characters long and it does no input validation. If you're using the compiler from Redmond that is [stuck in the 1980](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6688895/166749), use `unsigned long` instead of `uint32_t`.

Comment: Doesn't your function need to add the terminator to `buf` and add a `str+=8`?

Comment: @simonc: thanks, added that, and a caveat that the string should be properly padded.

Comment: It seems to me you could run afoul of endianness.

Comment: @HotLicks: The endianness of `strtoul`'s input is fixed and so is the endianness of `num`: both are little-endian. It's only inside the individual `uint32_t`s that endianness varies, but that's always true in C and it doesn't matter for the problem at hand.

Comment: Yes, but the endianness of the OP's discombobulation of the data is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `strtol` ?

```
int val = (int) strtol (hex_string, NULL, 16);
```

Repeat on substrings if it is a flattened array.

Regards