# How to print out C standard of Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

To know C++ standard that Visual Studio 2010 uses, I do this:

```
std::cout << __cplusplus;
```

the result is `199711` so C++ standard is C++98.

**What is the similar way to know C standard of Visual Studio 2010 ?**

**Edit:** I had read old posts about C/C++ standard of VS2010 and I knew VS2010 does not support C99 but these posts didn't mention the answer for my question.

Comment: Did you try checking the value of \_\_STDC\_VERSION\_\_? Oh, and first check if \_\_STDC\_\_ is even defined.

Comment: @2501 __STDC_VERSION__ is undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Microsoft visual studio 2010 support c99?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688895/does-microsoft-visual-studio-2010-support-c99)

Comment: It is actually C++03, not changing the number tends to happen with companies with a 1-800 support phone number.  2010 implements C89.

Comment: @BoPersson no. I read them. What I asked is the similar way to print the standard similar to cout<<__cplusplus

Comment: @IlDivin - In 1989 there wasn't any need to differentiate between different standards, so no such feature was added. VS2015 is *approaching* C99, that's how far MS has come.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point, if `_MSC_VER` is defined, assume only C89 support. [None of Microsoft's compilers officially support beyond the C89 standard.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146381/visual-studio-support-for-new-c-c-standards) Back in 1989, when the ANSI C standard was first released, there was no reason to check and see what version of it was supported—there was only one version. The designation C89 is itself a neologism.

If Bo's comment is right about VS 2015 approaching C99 support (I'm not sure, I haven't installed VS 2015, and you don't seem to care about that version in the question, either), you could test `_MSC_VER` for 1900 to detect that version.

That's what you would have to do even if the compiler supported a predefined macro like `__STDC_VERSION__` because they're not going to (at least, they're not supposed to) increment the version number until they have full support for the applicable standard. In other words, adding a few of C99's features wouldn't be enough to increment `__STDC_VERSION__`.

Comment: I've printed _MSC_VER, it is defined as 1600, what does is mean ? Does it represent a C standard ?

Comment: No, it tells you the version of Microsoft's compiler, in major-minor format. 1600 == version 16.0 == Visual C++ 16 == Visual Studio 2010

Comment: I've got it. Your answer satisfy me