# "Implicit declaration of function '_CGSDefaultConnection' is invalid in C99"

Tags: cocoa

I'm new to cocoa programming but I picked up a project and keep running into an error. The error is :

> "Implicit declaration of function '_CGSDefaultConnection' is invalid in C99"

I google'd it but couldn't find a definite answer as to what was wrong. But from what I can tell, the line `cid = (CGSConnectionID)_CGSDefaultConnection();` is not being defined in the correct way.

The full code is below:

```
#define kIconLevel -2147483628
+ (NSArray*)allIconRects
{
    NSMutableArray *rects = [NSMutableArray array];

    int results[1000];
    int count = -1;

    CGSConnectionID cid;
    cid = (CGSConnectionID)_CGSDefaultConnection();
    CGSGetWindowList( cid, 0, 1000, results, &count );

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        CGWindowLevel level;
        CGSGetWindowLevel( cid, results[i], &level );
        if (level == kIconLevel) {
            NSRect bounds;
            CGSGetWindowBounds(cid, results[i], (CGRect*) &bounds);
            [rects addObject:[NSValue valueWithRect:bounds]];
        }
    }

    return rects;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[C99 requires functions to be prototyped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575153/must-declare-function-prototype-in-c) before being used. As this is a hidden API, you need to tell the compiler to look for it at link time rather than in included header files:

```
extern CGSConnectionID _CGSDefaultConnection();
```

http://cocoadev.com/DontExposeMe

Comment: That get's rid of the error, but the next line calls upon the "cid", `CGSGetWindowList( cid, 0, 1000, results, &count );`. So would I need to do something like `cid = extern CGSConnectionID _CGSDefaultConnection();` (which I know throws a parse error.

Comment: @Charlie see the usage in the CocoaDev link, you do not use `extern` at the function call, you use it with the function prototype.