# Where is function err_sys() defined?

Tags: c, network-programming

I am getting an error related to `err_sys()` in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
int main()
{
    int sockfd;

    if ((sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0)
        err_sys("can't create socket");

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the linker error:

```
/tmp/cciuUVhz.o: In function `main':
getsockopt.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `err_sys'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Where is the function `err_sys()` defined?

Comment: Never heard of `err_sys` (so I've no idea how `getsockopt.cpp` compiles). Use `perror` or `strerror` instead. Also, you really need to start accepting some previous answers please. It's not hard!

Comment: @Tomalak: It probably compiles because warnings aren't turned up high enough, and the C standard allows you to not have prototypes declared for functions.

Comment: @Oli: ORLY? I don't use C, so I didn't know. That's horrid! (Which reminds me... I did of course mean `getsockopt.c` above)

Comment: @Tomalak: Indeed!  It is grim.  See the accepted answer here, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575153/must-declare-function-prototype-in-c.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Place this on top of your code:

```
void err_sys(const char* x) 
{ 
    perror(x); 
    exit(1); 
}
```

perror is defined in stdio.h

err_sys is used in the book "UNIX Network Programming: The sockets networking API" by Richard Stevens. It's not something common, as far as I know.

edit:fixed code error

Comment: Why not use a function for this, rather than a macro?

Comment: The macro as written has serious bugs, e.g. `if (foo) err_sys(x); else ...` fails. If you can't write a correct macro, use functions!

Comment: To write it as a macro, you'd need `#define err_sys(x) do { perror(x); exit(1); } while (0)`.  This does not run foul of the `if (foo) err_sys(x); else ...` problem.  It (`do { ... } while (0)`) is a standard technique.

Answer (score 7):

Is this from TCP/IP Illustrated?  I remember seeing this and the definition is provided in the appendix:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
/*
 * Print a message and return to caller.
 * Caller specifies "errnoflag".
 */
static void
err_doit(int errnoflag, int error, const char *fmt, va_list ap)
{
    char    buf[MAXLINE];
    vsnprintf(buf, MAXLINE, fmt, ap);
    if (errnoflag)
        snprintf(buf+strlen(buf), MAXLINE-strlen(buf), ": %s",
    strerror(error));
    strcat(buf, "\n");
    fflush(stdout);     /* in case stdout and stderr are the same */
    fputs(buf, stderr);
    fflush(NULL);       /* flushes all stdio output streams */
}


/*
 * Fatal error related to a system call.
 * Print a message and terminate.
 */
void
err_sys(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list     ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    err_doit(1, errno, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`err_sys()` is a function used in several books written by *W. Richard Stevens*. This function is used to print what type of error occurred.

The function is used in programs in the texts with a custom header file `"ourhdr.h"` (or something else). Check the appendix for the header listing or the function definition.

Answer (score 2):

The source for this function (from Advanced Programming in the UNIX® Environment, by W. Richard Stevens) can be found on the book's website: http://www.apuebook.com/.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify lib file which contains implementation for this function. 
That is common problem when compiling c code.

Comment: It's especially common when you're using a function that does not _have_ an implementation, because it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Download the source code folder of the book you will find it in:
http://www.unpbook.com/src.html

Open the source code folder and choose the lib folder. Next open the file called error.c. You will find the sys_err() defined in it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, this code looks like examples from Stevens: Unix Network Programming. If you have the book, look in appendix D: miscellaneous source code for the text book definition (as well as the unp.h header that is used pervasively in examples). The file is too much to type into a SO answer, but a quick internet search for Stevens "standard error functions" returns a lot of google books results with implementations.