# How to call this method in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, function, methods

i have seen this block of code in this Stackoverflow as a answer of some ones question,i tried to impliment that in my code but i am not getting what kind of function is this and how can i call that

```
NSString * ReplaceFirstNewLine(NSString * original)
{
    NSMutableString * newString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:original];

    NSRange foundRange = [original rangeOfString:@"\n"];
    if (foundRange.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        [newString replaceCharactersInRange:foundRange
                                 withString:@""];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",newString);
    return [[newString retain] autorelease];
}
```

i have tried to call this like `[self ReplaceFirstNewLine(@"\nstirng\nstring")];`
but its giving syntax error,can any one help me out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, it's not a `method`, it's a C `function`, similar to `NSLog`, so use it as such:

```
NSString *results = ReplaceFirstNewLine(@"\nstirng\nstring");
NSLog(@"%@", results);
```

C-style-functions have advantages and disadvantages, and I'll try to list some of them here:

Advantages:

- Speed. A C function is almost ALWAYS faster than an equivalent objective-c method, because there is no dynamic dispatch needed to call the function
- Pointers. It is much easier to get a pointer to a C-style function than it is to an Objective-C method, which makes it much better suited for C API callbacks

Disadvantages:

- iVars. In a C function, you **cannot** access the private variables of an object (even with a reference to it), without using runtime wizardry, at which point, it really isn't worth it.
- No concept of `self`. You cannot use the `self` (or `_cmd`, for that matter) variables inside a C function, as each C function is independent of other functions inside your product.

Comment: @Richard Could you please tell what kind of function is this. I only aware about methods of kind -(NSString)replaceFirstNewLine{ .... }; It seems to be C style function. Could you please provide some resource that I can refer about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ravi you are welcome. Do not forget to up-vote and accept the answer, though! It helps others find this easier.

Comment: @Ravi isn't my answer enough? If you don't understand what a C function is, I would pick up a book on C, keeping objective-c elements in the back of your head. It is a far too large of task to cover in one answer.

Comment: ya i can accept only after 10 minutes na(stack oveflw rule :-)),,  can we call this from other class?

Comment: Yes, if the function is not static, you can add a forwarding reference to it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575153/must-declare-function-prototype-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You would call it like this:  `ReplaceFirstNewLine(@"");`

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *) ReplaceFirstNewLine(NSString * original){
    //...
}
```

Now you should be abe to call it like a method:

```
[self ReplaceFirstNewLine(@"\nstirng\nstring")];
```