# Intro to C: Declaration of Functions

Tags: c, function, debugging, declaration, absolute-value

I want to declare a function for use in my code in ANSI C.
Am I allowed to define the function after using it in main()?
For example an absolute value function that I wrote: can anyone tell me if it's sound?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double value1 = -5;
    printf("%lf",
           abs(value1));
}

double abs(double number)
{
    if (number < 0) {
        (number * (-1) = number);
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: If it matters in any way you can use the abs function that does what you want and it exist in the math.h library (for c++) or cmath.h (for C).

Comment: @Edeph you got those includes backwards, `<cmath>` for C++ and `<math.h>` for C.

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry my bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to fix a couple of things:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double abs(double number); // <<< 1. prototype here

int main()
{
    double value1 = -5;

    printf("%lf",
           abs(value1));
}

double abs(double number)
{
    if (number < 0) {
        number = number * -1.0; // <<< 2. fix here
    }
    return number;
}
```

1. the `abs` function needs a prototype so that the compiler knows its *function signature* before you call it
2. your expression for negating `number` was back-to-front

Comment: +1. As a side note: it is not necessary required to declare a function prototype in C, although it is definitely a good practice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2575204/814702

Comment: @informatik01: in this case it *is* necessary, as default int parameters and function result will obviously not work.

Comment: In this case I agree. It was just a *general* side note. Couldn't help that, sorry )

Comment: @informatik01 It is however necessary to _declare_ a function before calling it, as explained in the answer you linked. A function prototype is a function declaration which specifies the type of the parameters. Obsolete versions of C allowed function definitions even without a declaration. This idiocy was removed in the C99 standard. Unfortunately, you are still allowed to declare functions with no parameters (non-prototype format), but it is flagged as an obsolete feature in the C standard.

Comment: @Lundin With all due respect, I never told about that you don't have to _declare_ a function before calling it. The **only** thing I wanted to empathize (and it was clearly stated in the answer I linked to, in the first sentence) is about function **prototype**. Although, as the author of that answer noted in his additional note, for *some* functions it is a requirement. And I of course agree with Paul R that in his example it was necessary. Anyways, thank you for you comment.

Answer (score 1):

Functions must at least be *declared* before they are used, preferably using prototype syntax (which specifies the number and types of arguments, as well as the return type).  So at the very least, you need a line like

```
double abs( double number );
```

somewhere in your code *before* you call `abs` in `main`.

You may also *define* a function before it is used:

```
double abs( double number )
{
   // compute absolute value
}

int main( void )
{
  ...
  x = abs(x);
  ...
}
```

This is actually my preference; everything in the same translation unit (file) should be *defined* before it's used.  This way you don't have to worry about keeping declarations and definitions in sync.