# Function pointer to "undefined" functions

Tags: c, gcc, function-pointers, objcopy

So, here is the problem.

I have compiled some object files, using `gcc -c`, and I have cloned them using `obj-copy`.
If the a function of the initial object file was named `foo()`, then the resulting function names in the cloned objects are:
`foo1(); foo2(); foo3();`

Then, I link those 3 objects, with another file, that contains the main method, and I can invoke each of the function variants by using e.g. `foo2();`. This work perfectly fine!

However, if I try to create a function pointer to point to those functions by using:

`functionPtr=&foo1; \\ tried also w/o the &`

then, I get:

`error: 'foo2' undeclared (first use in this function)`

Any ideas? Does this have to do with the linking?

Comment: Put a declaration of your functions in a header file and include this header file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you please follow my comment on answer by @TypeIA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo2` must be declared in a header file somewhere. You've cloned the object files, but the C compiler still needs something to tell it that there's a function called `foo2` and what its signature is. If you have a declaration somewhere for the original `foo`, just make a copy of that and change the name to `foo2`, and make sure the header is `#include`'d in your source.

Comment: But if I call `foo1();` it works. Why doesn't it work for `fPtr=&foo1;` too?

Comment: @Paschalis ANSI C [doesn't require a function prototype to call a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575153/must-declare-function-prototype-in-c); it infers the signature from the way you call it. It won't do that for function pointers, though.

Comment: So, to try understand the reasoning behind this: if I use `foo_99()`(which does not exist anywhere), it will pass the compilation, but will fail on linking. But in function pointers, it needs a reference to the function before the final linking. Is that corrrect?

Comment: Still, using funcions without prototype is frowned upon. It's a legacy from pre-standard c, and most compilers warn you or even treat it as an error if you so desire (you should!).

Comment: @Deduplicator I agree. But I was using a prototype `foo()`. And since I was relying to `obj-copy` to rename the reference of `foo()`, I was expecting to rename the prototype too!
This is why I got confused!