# why can't I build a no return type function in this program?

Tags: c, function, return, void

This is a small program to multiply and add two numbers using functions..

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{
 int a,b,result;
 clrscr();
 printf("Enter two numbers to be added and multiplied...\n");
 scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
add(a,b);
 getch();
 return 0;
}

int add(int a,int b)
{
int res;
 printf("%d + %d = %d", a,b,a+b);
 res=mult(a,b);
 printf("\n%d * %d = %d",a,b,res);
 return 0;
}

int mult(int a,int b)
{
 return a*b;
}
```

Although, I don't think that I need to have a return type add function,so I tried to use this code...

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{
 int a,b,result;
 clrscr();
 printf("Enter two numbers to be added and multiplied...\n");
 scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
add(a,b);
 getch();
 return 0;
}

void add(int a,int b)
{
int res;
 printf("%d + %d = %d", a,b,a+b);
 res=mult(a,b);
 printf("\n%d * %d = %d",a,b,res);
}

int mult(int a,int b)
{
 return a*b;
}
```

but it tells me that there's an error for mismatch type declaration??

Comment: you must declare the function before use, or better move the function to before main or before it's being used

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide a prototype before the first use:

```
void add(int a, int b); /* This tells the compiler that add() takes */
                        /* two ints and returns nothing.            */

int main() {
  ...
  add(a, b);
}

void add(int a, int b) {
  ...
}
```

Otherwise the compiler is obliged to assume that `add()` returns an `int`.

For more information, see [Must declare function prototype in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575153/must-declare-function-prototype-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to put **declaration** of functions before using it:

```
void add(int a,int b);
int mult(int a,int b);
```

Then you can put its **definition** wherever you want.

Or you can **declare & define** them before using.