# Implicit declaration of function and conflicting type - AVR

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, avr, atmega16

This is my first program for AVR. While building, the code is showing error:
conflicting types for 'Encode'
implicit declaration of 'Encode'

I have written the following code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SegDataPort PORTC
#define SegDataPin PINC
#define SegDataDDR DDRC

#define SegCntrlPort PORTD
#define SegCntrlPin PIND
#define SegCntrlDDR DDRD

int main(void)
{
   SegDataDDR = 0xFF;
   SegCntrlDDR = 0xF3;
   SegCntrlPort = 0xF3;
   SegDataPort = 0x00;
   unsigned char adc_value;
   float volt = adc_value/1023;
   int temp = floor(volt*10 + 0.5);

   SegDataPort = Encode(temp1%10);

   //^^^^ implicit declaration of 'Encode' 

   SegCntrlPort = ~0x01;
   SegDataPort = Encode((temp1/10)%10);
   SegCntrlPort = ~0x02;
   SegDataPort = Encode(temp1/100);
   SegCntrlPort = ~0x04;
}

unsigned char Encode(int digit)
{
   unsigned char val;
   switch(digit)
   {
      case 0 : Val = 0b00111111;
      case 1 : val = 0b00000110;

      /// so on till case 9
   }
   return val;
}
```

I am using ATmega16 as microcontroller. I have also added much more libraries such as math for floor function and others. I have tried changing int to unsigned int, unsigned char and others but it is still not working and showing same error. 
Please help me.

Comment: @mathematician1975 AFAIK, `PORTx` are AVR specific registers which can be used as normal c variables.  Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *implicit declaration of 'Encode'*

In `C` a function needs to be either *declared* or *defined* before it has been used (called).

Either

- Move the definition of `Encode()` function before `main()`
- Add a forward declaration to `Encode()` before `main()`.

That said, `floor()` is a function, defined in `math.h` and defined in the `math` library. To use that, you need to `#include <math.h>` and link with `-lm` at compilation time.

---

About the programmic logic used here,

```
unsigned char adc_value;
float volt = adc_value/1023;
int temp = floor(volt*10 + 0.5);
```

are pretty problematic, because

1. `adc_value` is used uninitialized, which leads to  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
2. `adc_value` is of type `char`. Dividing it by a value of `1023` will always give a result of `0` as the division will take place as an *integer division* and won't *produce* a `float` result itself, as you migh have expected.

My suggestions, change that code block to

```
int adc_value = <some value to initialize>;  //or some input function
float volt = (float)adc_value/1023;          //enforce floating point division
int temp = floor(volt*10 + 0.5);
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. But can you tell me why the function has to be called before in C. As this was not the case for C++ or Java or Python

Comment: @Yash called before? no, it's the other way, it has to be _declared_ before _called_. You can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2575153/2173917) for more info on this.

Answer (score 0):

**First mistake:**

```
 unsigned char adc_value;
 float volt = adc_value/1023;
```

You defind `adc_value` as an `unsigned char` and in the next line you tried to divide it by `1023` and assigned the result to a `float` type variable. You can't do these in `C` language. (More over you didn't assign any value to `adc_value`! it will be zero or a random value)

**Second mistake:**

Your second problem is that you defined your `Encode` function after calling it in `main()`. You must move the whole function before `main()` function or just add its prototype before the `main()` function.

i.e  add `unsigned char Encode(int digit);` before `main()`

**Thirst mistake:**

You tried to assign some values to those variables that you declared with `#define`:

```
#define SegDataPort PORTC
#define SegDataPin PINC
#define SegDataDDR DDRC

#define SegCntrlPort PORTD
#define SegCntrlPin PIND
#define SegCntrlDDR DDRD

int main(void)
{
   SegDataDDR = 0xFF;
   SegCntrlDDR = 0xF3;
   SegCntrlPort = 0xF3;
   SegDataPort = 0x00;
   .
   .
   .
```

This is illegal also. those variables that is defined with `#define`, are constant and you must not try to change them in the program body.

Comment: adc_value is my analog input. SO, it ranges from 0 to 1023.

Comment: With all due respect, would you mind checking your third point once more?

Comment: I'm not very sure, No experiece of AVR. Please verify [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30589109/implicit-declaration-of-function-and-conflicting-type-avr/30589168#comment49247557_30589109) once.

Comment: @Yash Its defined as an `unsigned char` so its value can be from `0` to `255`. (it has 8 bit length.) why you didn't defined it as `int`?

Comment: So, how can I say that ports of my microcontroller are input or output. I have found only this way while surfing.

Comment: I am reading its value directly from microcontroller input, I think that the input is of the form of 'char' only. Correct me if I'm wrong !!

Comment: @Yash `PORTx` and `DDRx` are two different variable. the first specify the voltage of output and the latter specify the direction.

Comment: @Yash For example when `DDRD=0xff` then D is output and for output ports `PORTD=0xff` means all the pins are 5 volt. and `PORTD=0x00` means all the pins of this port are 0 volt. When `DDRD=0x00` the D is input and tor input ports `PORTD=0xFF` means that all the pins are pulled-up with inner resistors, while `PORTD=0x00` means that they are not pulled-up.

Comment: the #define is NOT creating a variable, rather it is a 'text substitution'  that occurs at beginning of the compile operation.  so, wherever one of those #define names is used, it is actually (in this case) an access to the associated hardware register.

Comment: regarding 'first mistake'  There is a second problem in the same code lines.   When working with 'float' values, the literals need to be of the format that includes a '.' and is trailed by 'f'.    The '.' to make the literal non-integer and the 'f' to make it float.  without the 'f' it is a double.