# How do I use Structs?

Tags: c, struct

Making a new question, cause my old one died after taking to long to edit it.
So I am trying to get rid of all these parameters in this code (Yes, some of the parameters are redundant but I just added them incase):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //Top coord. of the square
    int top_x1 = 0;
    int top_y1 = 10;
    int top_x2 = 10;
    int top_y2 = 10;

    //Bottom coord. of the square
    int bottom_x1 = 0;
    int bottom_y1 = 0;
    int bottom_x2 = 10;
    int bottom_y2 = 0;

    //Left coord. of the square
    int left_x1 = 0;
    int left_y1 = 0;
    int left_x2 = 0;
    int left_y2 = 10;

    //Right coord. of the square
    int right_x1 = 10;
    int right_y1 = 0;
    int right_x2 = 10;
    int right_y2 = 10;

    parameter(top_x1, top_y1, top_x2, top_y2, bottom_x1,
              bottom_y1, bottom_x2, bottom_y2, left_x1,
              left_y1, left_x2, left_y2, right_x1, right_y1,
              right_x2, right_y2);
}

parameter (int top_x1,int top_y1,int top_x2,int top_y2,int bottom_x1,
              int bottom_y1,int bottom_x2,int bottom_y2,int left_x1,
              int left_y1,int left_x2,int left_y2,int right_x1,int right_y1,
              int right_x2,int right_y2)
{
    int totalParameter, topSide, bottomSide, leftSide, rightSide;

    topSide = (top_x2 - top_x1);
    bottomSide = (bottom_x2 - bottom_x1);
    leftSide = (left_y2 - left_y1);
    rightSide = (right_y2 - right_y1);

    totalParameter = (topSide + bottomSide + leftSide + rightSide);
    printf("%d\n", totalParameter);

}
```

works perfectly but too many parameters! If I try using structs...

```
#include <stdio.h>>

struct coordinates
{
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
};

int main()
{
    struct coordinates top;
    struct coordinates bottom;
    struct coordinates left;
    struct coordinates right;

    //Top line of the square
    top.x1 = 0;
    top.y1 = 10;
    top.x2 = 10;
    top.y2 = 10;

    //Bottom line of the square
    bottom.x1 = 0;
    bottom.y1 = 0;
    bottom.x2 = 10;
    bottom.y2 = 0;

    //Left line of the square
    left.x1 = 0;
    left.y1 = 0;
    left.x2 = 0;
    left.y2 = 10;

    //Right line of the square
    right.x1 = 10;
    right.y1 = 0;
    right.x2 = 10;
    right.y2 = 10;

    parameter(top,bottom,left,right);
}

parameter(top, bottom, left, right)
{
    int totalParameter, topSide, bottomSide, leftSide, rightSide;

    topSide = (top.x2 - top.x1);
    bottomSide = (bottom.x2 - bottom.x1);
    leftSide = (left.y2 - left.y1);
    rightSide = (right.y2 - right.y1);

    totalParameter = topSide + bottomSide + leftSide + rightSide;
    printf("%d\n", totalParameter);
```

}

I want it to print out: 40.

Doesn't work though, any help please?
Error I get is: "Request for member 'x1' in something not a structure of union.
For all the x and y coords.

Comment: Why are there no type specifiers in the signature of 'parameter'?

Comment: Firstly, in C language you have to declare function before you use them. Secondly, you first variant declared all parameters of `parameter` function with types. In the second variant you suddenly removed parameter types. Why did you remove the types?

Answer (score 2):

The function needs its return type defined and the type of its parameters defined, like so:

```
void parameter(struct coordinates top, struct coordinates bottom, struct coordinates left, struct coordinates right)
```

If you don't, the parameters default to type `int` (which is more of a history lesson in C than anything else). If you aren't forward declaring the function too, then it's being [implicitly declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508503/is-implicit-function-declaration-legal-in-c89) (which is illegal in modern C) and assumes your parameter and function types are different than what they should be (they all default to type `int`).