# Pass argv to function to populate global variable

Tags: c, argv

I'm trying to populate a global int variable by passing command line arguments to a function. When I do this, I get warnings (see below), as well as a funky return number (such as 52 instead of the expected 49).

Any hints would be greatly appreciated. This is HW - but only a very small portion of the overall assignment.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "kangarooHeaders.h"


int             numJoeys                = MIN_NUM_LEGAL_JOEYS - 1;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
        initializeNumJoeys(argc,argv);
        printf("%d", numJoeys);
}

void initializeNumJoeys(void argc, void *argv[])
{
        char line[LINE_LEN];
        if (argc > MAMAS_NUM_JOEYS_CMD_LINE_INDEX)
                numJoeys = *argv[1];
}
```

---

```
argv_test.c:13: warning: conflicting types for ‘initializeNumJoeys’
argv_test.c:9: warning: previous implicit declaration of ‘initializeNumJoeys’ was here
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a dupe, but it should help you understand the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434763/are-prototypes-required-for-all-functions-in-c89-c90-or-c99

Comment: `void argc` ??? `void *argv[]` ???  You have to pass compatible arguments to `initializeNumJoeys`  and neither `void` is compatible with `int` nor `void **` is compatible with `char **`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this above the `main()` function

```
void initializeNumJoeys(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

the reason is implicit function declaration, the compiler doesn't find a prototype for `initializeNumJoeys()` and implicitly declares it as

```
int initializeNumJoeys();
```

so when it finds the definition, then it's conflicting with the previous declaration.

Also, change this

```
numJoeys = *argv[1];
```

to

```
numJoeys = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
```

and also, the function signature is wrong

```
void initializeNumJoeys(void argc, void *argv[])
             /*           ^ should be int */
```

so change it to

```
void initializeNumJoeys(int argc, void *argv[])
```

don't forget to fix the prototype.

Comment: Ah, yes! The order matters - main should always go on bottom. Thank you iharob.

Comment: Not `main()`,  if you invoke any function that is not yet defined, a previous declaration of the function is required by the compiler, so you can have just that, a declaration of the function or "_a function prototype_".

Comment: I tried your suggestion (see edit). I no longer receive compiler warnings, but am still receiving the same incorrect number (52).

Comment: @user1185790 Don't edit your question in such a way that invalidates the answer.

Comment: My apologies. The latest `strtol` suggest results in the following errors argv_test.c:16: error: parameter 1 (‘argc’) has incomplete type
argv_test.c:17: error: conflicting types for ‘initializeNumJoeys’
argv_test.c:8: error: previous declaration of ‘initializeNumJoeys’ was here

Comment: Wow, thank you. So many bugs. Ugh. I wish gcc would be more detailed in explaining the problem.

Comment: @user1185790 `gcc` can be very detailed just add this options to `gcc` command `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`

Comment: The function is implicitly declared as `int initializeNumJoeys()`, and the compiler may assume that it is defined as taking an `int` and a `char **` (and needn't diagnose if it isn't).

Comment: @mafso I wasn't sure about that part.

Comment: Well, who still makes use of implicit declarations? As a suggestion for the answer: it could be pointed out, that C99 (`-std=c99 -pedantic` for GCC) removed implicit declarations, and maybe that a compiler (for any standard) needn't even diagnose the mismatch, as the function declarations aren't in the same scope (of course, a good compiler does warn).