# Function without any return type

Tags: c, function

I know there are two types of functions: `void` and the ones that return something (int, double, etc). But what if a function is declared without any return statements? Is it considered to be a `void` function? For example,

```
myFunction(int value){
.......
}
```

Comment: In the "olden days" that would default to `int`. Not sure if that is still the correct interpretation...

Comment: @John3136 that was true up until C99 . Since then it's ill-formed.

Comment: @M.M Thanks. I suspected it may not be right anymore. I was tempted to ask "why would anyone want to do it anyway", but that isn't really relevant!

Answer (score 5):

A function declared without any return type is considered returning an `int`. This is an ancient rule going back to the original K&R C, left in the language for backward compatibility.

Integer promotions and conversion of `float` arguments to `double`s are done for functions without prior definition or forward declaration for the same reason - backward compatibility with really old code.

It is needless to say that relying on these rules for new development is a very bad practice. One should always declare return type explicitly, and forward-declare or define all functions before calling them.

Comment: Aren't undeclared functions treated as if they were declared with an unspecified parameter list (`()`) ?

Comment: @Quentin Thanks! You are right, it's the same rules as with unspecified parameter lists (int promotions, floats become doubles, etc.)

Comment: @Quentin in C89, calling an undeclared function acted as if the function had been declared `int f();` . Since C99 that rule was removed and it's ill-formed to call an undeclared function.

Comment: The rule about omitted return type meaning `int` was also removed in C99. Now this code is ill-formed.

Comment: To quote the SO C tag usage: "Unless the question does explicitly mention which version of the C standard that is used, it is assumed that the current version is used. That is, whichever version of ISO 9899 that ISO currently lists as active. Please have this in mind when answering/commenting questions tagged C."

Answer (score 0):

First off, I have to say that your code:

```
myFunction(int value){
.......
}
```

is a function **definition**, other than just a **declaration**. A pure declaration will be like:

```
myFunction(int value);
```

or

```
myFunction(int);    //also valid but less recommended due to bad readability
```

Also note that every definition can serve as a declaration of the function, but not vise versa.

Let's go back to your question. `myFunction(int value);` is equal to `int myFunction(int value);` according to earlier standards. In fact, compilers will assume all undeclared functions to return an `int` using these standards.

However, a prototype without a type isn't a function declaration since C99, although the type is very likely to still be seen as `int` by a compiler.

Any way, this is a very bad coding style and should be avoided, because compile-time checking cannot be performed and you are depending on undefined behaviors, which are never trustworthy. If you don't need a return value, you can just write:

```
void myFunction(int value);
```

See also: [Are prototypes required for all functions in C89, C90 or C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434763/are-prototypes-required-for-all-functions-in-c89-c90-or-c99)

Answer (score 0):

If your standard compiler is set to correctly to compile according to the C standard, such functions are not allowed.

For example `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall`.

If you have a 20+ year old compiler, such functions were allowed though. The return type would then default to `int` if not stated explicitly. Similarly if no function prototype was visible, the compiler would make up a nonsense function declaration based on the function call, where the return type would default to `int`, if no prototype was visible.

There was never any rationale for why the "implicit int" feature made sense. What it did in practice was to block the compiler from static type checks and therefore created countless of bugs.

The dangerous, "implicit int" was therefore promptly removed from the C language in 1999.

This is actually one of the main reasons why you shouldn't be using a C compiler that follows some ancient version of the C language in the year 2016.