# Correct way to define a prototype

Tags: c, prototype

Came across a situation where I was in doubt how to define the prototype the correct way. It´s easier to just look at a simple example:

Document A.c:

```
#define foo bar

void mon() {
  foo();
}
```

Document B.c:

```
void bar() {
  Do something;
}
```

Gives following warning:

Warning: Function does not have a full prototype

Normally I would solve it by:

```
extern void foo(void);
```

But as example show, the function dont exactly exist but is defined to point on another function. What is the correct way to make a prototype for this?

Comment: It's not defined to point to another function. It's a preprocessor directive that specifies token substitution. The function isn't declared at all.

Comment: `#define foo bar` What on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, Hey, I am not trying to do anything. This warning comes from Umon bootloader, so I am just trying to "correct" their way of thinking

Comment: @StoryTeller, Sorry, bad choice of word from my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the compiler encounters the declaration `extern void foo(void);` **after** the `#define foo bar` for the same source file, it will parse it as `extern void bar(void);`  And the linker will just solve the `bar` symbol.

Note that you definition of `bar` is not consistent with the declaration above.  The definition of `bar` should read:

```
void bar(void) {
    // Do something;
}
```

in C, unlike C++, an argument list of `(void)` is subtly different from an empty argument list.

Comment: Hey, thanks! That actually makes sense. So the correct way is to do as I always have

Answer (score 0):

I think, that what happens is the following:

The compiler replaces the macro `foo` with `bar` but since at that stage `bar` is not declared anywhere as a function the compiler will complain, that it cannot find it.

Please see more: [Are prototypes required for all functions in C89, C90 or C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434763/are-prototypes-required-for-all-functions-in-c89-c90-or-c99)