# FMA intrinsics not working: is it Hardware or Compiler?

Tags: c, x86, simd, intrinsics, fma

I'm trying to use the Intel FMA intrinsics like **_mm_fmadd_ps (__m128 a, __m128 b, __m128 c)** in order to get better performance in my code.

So, first of all, i did a little test program to see what it can do and how can I possibly use them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "xmmintrin.h"

int main()
{
   __m128 v1,v2,v3,vr;
   v1 = _mm_set_ps (5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0);
   v2 = _mm_set_ps (2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0);
   v3 = _mm_set_ps (3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0);

   vr = _mm_fmadd_ps (v1, v2, v3);
}
```

and i've got this error :

**vr = error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘__m128’ from type ‘int’ vr = _mm_fmadd_ps (v1, v2, v3);**

I thought it was probably the processor capabilities is not allowing the use of such instructions so I looked on the internet for my processor model ([Intel® Core™ i7-4700MQ Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/75117/Intel-Core-i7-4700MQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_40-GHz)) and I found out that it supports only **SSE4.1/4.2, AVX 2.0** intrinsics which was a little bit weird for me!!
So I looked in the proc/cpuinfo file and the flags section I found the ** *fma* ** flag. This is the confusing part about the hardware.

As for the software, i've used this makefile option after some digging on the internet and I hope it's not the issue.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -c -Wall -O2 -mavx2 -mfma
```

And I'm using eclipse on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with a GCC version 4.9.4
Thank you.

Comment: You need [`#include <immintrin.h>`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_fmadd_ps&expand=2389,2389).

Comment: That is a *compiler* error. The code hasn't even started running yet, so it cannot possibly be lack of support from your chip.

Comment: @PaulR : it worked .... Thank you

Comment: Note that this code does nothing useful, so when you compile it with optimizations enabled (`-O2`), the compiler elides all this code and simply emits code to return 0 from `main` ([demo](https://godbolt.org/g/YjDY6s)). So it'll run *real* fast. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray: true - making `vr` `volatile` fixes this though, if you just want to [see the generated code](https://godbolt.org/g/dm8Ptq).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the quirks of C is that the language indicates that the compiler is to assume a symbol it's not seen before must return `int` if you call it like a function. Since you didn't include the header that actually defines the signature for `_mm_fmadd_ps`, you get the strange error about converting `int` to `__m128`.

The original organization of the intrinsics headers was to have a unique header per instruction generations, so you had:

```
mmintrin.h     The original MMX instruction set (deprecated for x64 native)
mm3dnow.h      The AMD 3D Now! instruction set (deprecated for x64 native)
emmintrin.h    SSE (i.e. single-precision 4-wide SIMD)
xmmintrin.h    SSE2 (i.e. double-precision and integer 4-wide SIMD)
```

After that, they started using the code names of the processor architecture where the new instructions were introduced.

```
pmmintrin.h    SSE3 (the p stands for Prescott)
tmmintrin.h    Supplemental SSE3 (the t stands for Tejas)
smmintrin.h    SSE4.1 (not sure what the s is here for.
               They were added for Penryn but p
               was already used for Prescott)
nmmintrin.h    SSE4.2 (the n stands for Nehalem)
wmmintrin.h    AES (the w stands for Westmere)
```

These days the new instruction sets tend to end up in either `ammintrin.h` for AMD-originated stuff (ABM, BMI, LWP, TBM, XOP, FMA4, SSE4a, SSE5) or `immintrin.h` for Intel-originated stuff (AVX, FMA3, F16C, AVX2, etc.). AVX-512 is in `zmmintrin.h`.

The older system wasn't particularly intuitive, but neither is the new one. A number of AMD instruction subsets are defined in `immintrin.h` because they are the same instruction. Looking it up in the documentation or the header is really the only way to know which intrinsic is where.

For Intel [this website](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) is a good reference. Otherwise you need to see the developer guides for [AMD](http://developer.amd.com/resources/developer-guides-manuals/) and/or [Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm).

You might find [this blog series of mine](https://walbourn.github.io/directxmath-sse-sse2-and-arm-neon/) useful.

Comment: the quirk does not apply to C++ and C99+ because [there are no implicit int in those standards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/434763/995714)

Comment: Why not just include `x86intrin.h` and set your build flags accordingly? Saves a lot of time in having to remember all these crazy, unintuitive names.

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't use any intrinsic unless you know exactly what platform it's supported on. Otherwise, you can easily end up writing a program that doesn't run on as many systems as you think it should. Just including everything is probably overkill and you *still* need to look up each instruction to really understand it.

Comment: That's true. The issue is, I remember the instruction mnemonics and which instruction set they are part of, just not these `?mmintrin.h` names. I guess I could look those up, too, but I've never found a good reason to do so.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn, `x86intrin.h` is for GCC and Clang where you define the hardware at compile time e.g. with `-msse4.2` so you only get the intrinsics that you choose at compile time. `x86intrin.h` is the logical choice for these compilers. For MSVC you don't generally define the hardware  (except VEX encoding and a few others) so it will let you use whatever intrinsics you include.

Comment: For the record, **`immintrin.h` is the portable catch-all for Intel *SIMD* intrinsics and is what most SIMD code should be using**, instead of futzing with other specific headers.  (It's the only portable way to use AVX or later intrinsics.) GCC/clang `x86intrin.h` vs. MSVC `intrin.h` have some scalar intrinsics like for BSF/BSR bit-scan.

Answer (score 1):

The -mfma  might seem like a bit of a bother, but it's there for good reason. The result of

```
_mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(a, b), c)
_mm_fmadd_ps(a, b, c)
```

Actually differ. If you are writing code that must compute the exact same results on all the machines you run the code on (determinism), then you will probably need to disable fma! That's basically why you need to enable it in the build with -fma.

Still, at least it's not as bad as the six compile flags you'll need for avx512 enabled SkyLake-X CPUs :(

Comment: FYI, for Visual C++ use of FMA3 is implied by ``/arch:AVX2``. The compiler will not always emit a true FMA3 instruction even when you use an FMA3 instrinsic as the compiler determines proper codegen based on the use context.

Comment: What 6 compile flags for SKX?  `-march=skylake-avx512` works just fine, and implies useful `-mtune=` settings.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true (anymore). Because at least gcc will replace `_mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(a, b), c)` with `_mm_fmadd_ps(a, b, c)` on some platforms even without -fma enabled.