# Which are the differences between generic pointer in C and generic pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, c

For my exam I must be explain differences of the generic pointer (`void *`) in C and C++. They are two different things, but I can't find the differences between them.

Comment: To spice things up further, modern C also has `_Generic`. Maybe you could post a code example.

Comment: "Unlike ANSI C, a generic pointer is not assignment-compatible with an arbitrary pointer type. This means C++ requires that generic pointers be cast to an explicit type for assignment to a nongeneric pointer value." [Link](https://www.ooportal.com/programming-cplus-plus/module4/generic-pointer-type.php)

Comment: @NicolBolas I corrected it. Yew, it's the void * in C and C++

Comment: @lucidbrot thank you for your anwser

Comment: The generic pointer type in C++ is `template <typename T> using ptr_t = T*` ;)

Answer (score 6):

In C, a `void *` pointer implicitly casts to any other pointer type. In C++, this cast must be made explicitly.

In C, `malloc` is used and we have [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) (no); while in C++ `malloc` is frowned upon, the cast is required, but failing to include `stdlib.h` is a compile error. `new` returns the correct pointer type.

Other things went similar in C++; you shouldn't be downcasting `void *` much anymore. I only do it when interoping with C code or weird code optimization where `template <class T>` uses lots of `T*` and I can do most of the work in a non-generic base class (very rare).

However neither language quite has generic pointers. `void *` and `void (*)()` are not actually required to be the same size. `void (*)()` is used for the generic function pointer. In C, implicitly casting to/from it is a warning while in C++ this is an error. Most people cast explicitly in C because suppressing all "suspicious pointer conversion" warnings is a bad idea.

Comment: that is the only one difference?

Comment: Faling to include `<stdlib.h>` is an error in both languages. Though C was a long time a bit more tolerant, due to the late introduction of prototypes, shifting the exact error observed.

Comment: Nit-pick. `void*` implicitly _converts_ to any other pointer type. A cast is an explicit conversion, made by the programmer.

Comment: @Mitch: added remaining esoteric case.

Comment: @Joshua Ehm. Yes, I *said* it was an error in both, though the exact manifestation is different.

Comment: Consider reading "*[Are prototypes required for all functions in C89, C90 or C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434763/are-prototypes-required-for-all-functions-in-c89-c90-or-c99)*" for how things evolved in C.