# Can't understand how to create a prototype of a procedure without parameters

Tags: c, function, prototype

My book says that I should write a prototype of a procedure (that hasn't any parameters) like this: `void test(void);`

I usually write the prototype of a procedure that hasn't any parameters like this: `void test();` and it works.

What is the difference between these 2 declarations?

Comment: The difference is that `void test();` doesn't establish a prototype, so you can later call `test("abc")` and `test(1)` and `test(&ptr, &str, &wotnot)` and they're all valid calls.

Comment: See [Are prototypes required for all functions in C89, C90 or C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434763/are-prototypes-required-for-all-functions-in-c89-c90-or-c99)  Note that this is not directly a duplicate of that, though they cover some of the same territory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, an empty parameter list in a function *declaration* means that the function takes an *unspecified* number of arguments - in a *definition*, it means it takes *no* arguments:

```
void foo(); // declaration, number of arguments is unspecified

void foo()  // definition, number of arguments is zero
{
  ...
}
```

A parameter list of `void` in both a declaration and a definition means the function takes no arguments:

```
void foo( void ); // declaration, number of arguments is 0

void foo( void )  // definition, number of arguments is 0
{
  ...
}
```

So why is this the case?

Neither prototype declaration syntax nor the `void` keyword were originally part of C - there was no way to specify "this function doesn't return a value" and "this function takes this many arguments of this type".  In the early Cretaceous, function definitions were written as

```
foo( a, b, c ) // return type of int assumed
   T a; // for arbitrary types T, Q, R
   Q b;
   R c;
 {
   // do something interesting with a, b, and c
 }
```

and the corresponding declaration was simply written as

```
foo(); // strictly not necessary, since the compiler would assume a return type of int
```

C originally had no mechanism to validate the number and types of arguments in a function *call* against a function declaration.  If you called `foo` as

```
foo( x, y, z, oops );
```

the compiler couldn't tell you that you'd passed too many arguments, or that any of `x`, `y`, or `z` were the wrong type. You wouldn't know that there was a problem until runtime.

The 1989 standard introduced the `void` keyword along with function prototype syntax, so you could now specify the number and types of parameters in a function *declaration*, allowing the compiler to catch mismatches like the above:

```
void foo( T, Q, R ); // only need to specify types in a declaration

void foo( T a, Q b, R c )
{
  // do something interesting with a, b, c
}
```

and the `void` keyword as a parameter list meant that the function took *no* parameters:

```
void foo( void );
```

Because legacy code is forever, old-style function definitions and declarations are still supported, although implicit `int` typing no longer is.  That's why you can still *declare* a function as `void foo();`, although best practice is to declare it as `void foo( void );` if it takes no arguments.  Otherwise, if you try to call `foo` with an argument like

```
foo( x );
```

the compiler will not be able to catch the mismatch.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! Very useful!

Answer (score 1):

This might be a difference between C and C++.

```
void test(void);
```

Is more of a C idiom.

```
void test();
```

Is more of a C++ idiom.

Comment: This is certainly a difference between C and C++.  In C++, the notation `void test();` declares that the function takes zero arguments, whereas in C, the same notation says "there is a function called `test` that returns no value and takes an indeterminate argument list — but it isn't a variadic function (with `, ...` at the end of the definition)".

Comment: Thank you so much!