# Are there advantages of declaring functions before, after or inside main()?

Tags: c, function, declaration, program-entry-point

I'm trying to learn C language for embedded systems. At the moment I'm learning the basics and couldn't find an answer to one of a fundamental question. When I wrote a simple C program I declared a function called maximum() in three ways. I will explain it by the following examples:

**1-)** Here in the below program the function is declared outside and before the main:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int maximum(int x, int y)
 {
    int z;
    z = (x >= y) ? x : y;
    return z;
}

int main(void)
{
    int result = maximum(30, 50);
    printf("%d", result);
    return(0);
}
```

**2-)** And now below the function is declared outside and after the main:

```
#include <stdio.h>    

int main(void)
{
    int result = maximum(30, 50);
    printf("%d", result);
    return(0);
}

int maximum(int x, int y)
 {
    int z;
    z = (x >= y) ? x : y;
    return z;
}
```

**3-)** And finally below the function is declared inside the main:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int maximum(int x, int y)
 {
    int z;
    z = (x >= y) ? x : y;
    return z;
 }
    int result = maximum(30, 50);
    printf("%d", result);
    return(0);
}
```

I tried all those above and all executes without error. Is there any reason to prefer one to the others?

Comment: Option 1) is OK, Option 2) lead to compiler warning without function declaration because it is out of main function scope. To tell the truth I'm working with C long time ago but I have never tried the Option 3). :-) It makes no sense to me since it is created locally inside your function and cannot be accessed from outside I guess.

Comment: Option 3 works with many compilers, but is not a valid c construct. If you prefer Option 1 or Option 2 is a matter of style, but for 2 you need a declaration before the first usage

Comment: Option 3 is not portable.

Comment: @Ctx: Option 3 is valid C; it is conforming C. It is not strictly conforming C.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Where exactly is the difference between "conforming" and "strictly conforming"?

Comment: @Ctx: The C standard invites extensions. C was designed to be portable, not just in a “this program can run everywhere” sense but “here is a core language that can be used everywhere with whatever extensions are useful on your system” sense. A *strictly conforming program* uses only the features fully defined in the C standard—it does not depend on unspecified, undefined, or implementation-defined behavior. A *conforming implementation* is one that accepts any strictly conforming program. A *conforming program* is any program acceptable to some conforming implementation…

Comment: @Ctx: … So a valid C program—one that is conforming—is any program that fits into the syntax well enough to be accepted by some implementation, with whatever extensions it has, including function definitions inside a function. C was intended to include these kinds of programs. The fixation on Stack Overflow about denying anything outside of the core language (strictly conforming programs) is not in the spirit of the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: So my compiler Ctxcc, which looks like `gcc $1 || ghc $1` now magically makes whole Haskell "conforming c" (albeit not strictly-conforming, of course), by implementing a "conforming compiler", that tries to translate haskell if it fails as plain c. That definition does not sound very convincing, but you are correct, I looked it up in the standard, too. However, I did not say "conforming", but "valid c construct", with which I mean, that it is not supported by the standard.

Answer (score 7):

In standard C since C99, it is necessary to *declare* functions before you call them.  This tells the compiler what type to expect of the return value, how many arguments it should pass, how it might need to convert them to correctly match the function's parameter types.  That declaration does not need to be a *definition* of the function, however, and frequently it isn't.

Your (1) is fine in this regard, but your (2) is non-conforming.  However, (2) happens to have return and parameter types that are consistent with older C expectations for calling an undeclared function, and many compilers will accept it and do the right thing with it under some circumstances.

Your (3) is non-conforming in a different way: C does not allow nested functions.  You may put a function declaration inside another function, though there is little advantage to this, but not a whole function definition.  One compiler family I know does accept that as an extension, and maybe others do, too, but under no circumstances should you rely on that.

Thus, of the three alternatives presented, (1) is the only one you should use.  If you want to have more freedom to place the `maximum()` function then provide a forward declaration, with prototype, near the top of the file:

**(4)**

```
#include <stdio.h>    

// Forward declaration, including prototype:
int maximum(int x, int y);

int main(void)
{
    int result = maximum(30, 50);
    printf("%d", result);
    return(0);
}

int maximum(int x, int y)
 {
    int z;
    z = (x >= y) ? x : y;
    return z;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Option 1 is valid and it works, but it tends to hide the `main` function at the end of your program.

Option 2 is not valid starting with C99 where there's no "default `int`" anymore.

Option 3 is not valid although many compilers support it.

What I would suggest is a mix of options 1 and 2. Declare the function prototype before `main` and define it later in the file:

```
#include <stdio.h>    

int maximum(int x, int y);

int main(void)
{
    int result = maximum(30, 50);
    printf("%d", result);
    return(0);
}

int maximum(int x, int y)
 {
    int z;
    z = (x >= y) ? x : y;
    return z;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a duplicate, but here goes.  For a function defined in the same file where `main` is defined:

- If you define it before `main`, you only have to define it; you don't have to declare it and separately define it.
- If you define it after `main`, you have to put a matching prototype declaration before `main`.  But the advantage is that your source file then reads more naturally: a reader can start at the top and see what `main` does, without getting distracted by a bunch of utility functions.
- If you want to define it *inside* `main`, you're stuck, because standard C doesn't have nested functions.  (Some compilers do offer it as an extension.)

For a function defined in some other source file than the file where `main` is defined, you just need the function prototype declarations before `main` -- typically/preferably/ideally via an `#include` file.

In the end this is a question of style, without a single, objective answer (other than that nested functions aren't Standard).  Different programmers can and do make different choices.  If your company or other institution has a style guide, it might weigh in on this question.  Me, I usually prefer to put `main` first and function definitions below it, but I'm not dogmatic about it.

Answer (score 3):

Basically if you declare functions inside another function, which main is, it's only available in that scope. So for example, if you want to call `maximum` from another file, you won't be able to do it.

Declaring functions outside main is preferred when you want to call it externally and also very beneficial in terms of code readability and maintainability.

Comment: *Declaring* one function inside another is not exclusive of also declaring it outside.  The scope of the declared function is not restricted, just the scope of that one declaration.  *Defining* one function inside another might have semantics such as you describe, but it might also have any other semantics whatever, because standard C does not provide for nested function definitions.  The OP's (3) is trying to do the latter.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to write C is to always provide a function prototype.

But if you're coding to a C "dialect" (C89, for example) where function prototypes are not required, one huge advantage of prototypes - getting the **type** of the return value right.  If you change your original code that doesn't have a prototype so the return value is not `int`, the compiler will (depending on the version of the C standard you are compiling against) assume it returns `int` and not what the function actually returns.  For example if you change your code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>    

int main(void)
{
    int *result = maximum(30, 50);
    printf("%d", *result);
    return(0);
}

/* now returns int * and not
   just int */
int *maximum(int x, int y)
 {
    static int z;
    z = (x >= y) ? x : y;
    return &z;
}
```

and serious problems can arise.

Why?

Because, depending on your "dialect" of C based upon your exact compiler and the arguments you pass it (for example, you wind up applying the C89 standard for some reason), calling a function without a prototype will cause the compiler to assume the function returns `int` even though it actually returns `int *`.  See [**Calling a C Function without Prototype**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434763/are-prototypes-required-for-all-functions-in-c89-c90-or-c99) and [**Are prototypes required for all functions in C89, C90 or C99?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434763/are-prototypes-required-for-all-functions-in-c89-c90-or-c99) (and follow the linked questions) for a full discussion.

The TLDR; *safe* answer to "Are function prototypes required in C?" is "Not always.  But if you don't have one, you can get some serious problems."

So, in this example, even though `maximum()` is defined to return an `int *`, **the compiler assumes it actually returns `int`**.

That won't work well.  It can work silently, it can fail silently, it can fail obviously.

See [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) for a specific discussion with respect to `malloc()`.

**Extra warning**

And never, ever, ever provide a prototype for a function that's defined in the old K&R style:

```
int function( a, p )
    int a;
    char *p
{
    ....
}
```

Doing that will break things even worse.  Old K&R style functions expect all their arguments that have been passed have undergone [default argument promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls).  That's the same thing that happens to the variable arguments passed to functions like `printf()`.  But if you provide a function prototype, the arguments will not be promoted.  If you pass a `float` to a function expecting its to have undergone promotion, the function will expect a `double`, for example.

So if you run into old, old K&R style C code, you won't be helping things and will actually cause all kinds of problems if you provide prototypes for all the function calls - unless you rewrite the function definitions also.

Comment: NMDV, but I had to read this twice to recognize that you were not, in fact, recommending the second code over the first.

Comment: @JohnBollinger There seems to have been an upsurge in drive-by DVs lately.  Either that or I have a stalker.  Well, if that's what makes someone feel better, I'll give up all those two points.

Comment: The first revision doesn't even really relate to the problem the OP is having. I get that it's an important point, but it's not relevant. The second revision is better, so I'll go ahead and give you those 2 points back.

Answer (score 0):

From working with large projects (1000+ files), I think it is more important to make it easier for read the files. This implies placing the 'major' functions of a module (using the 'public' API, or `main`) at the top. It make it easier for readers to find the 'beef'.

Following this logic, other functions (maximum in this case), should be declared before the 'major' functions (to get type-checking, clean build), and placed toward the bottom of the file.

```
// header file describing the 'public' API
#include "header.h"

static int maximum(int x, int y);

// Public API
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ...
   maximum(...);
}

char *other_function(...)
{
   ...
}

// Static "private" functions
static int maximum(int x, int y)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally say option 2 but you need to declare it above int main void

Reasoning behind this is at the moment the code is very simple but as you work on larger projects you don't want to have to scroll pages and pages to get to your main function

Answer (score -1):

I do not advise to use option 3, option 1 is the best as I use it often... Anyways main() is the entry point of your application... I do not think that any of the methods 1 or 2 affect the performance of your application... If you  use method 2 its good you prototype it since according to C99 standard its **invalid** and compliers generate **warning** for **implicit declaration** . But when designing code **readability** should be a paramount concern as we even the programmers could get lost in maze of confusion... I advise you to put your functions dedicated to a particular task in a separate **header file** 
Happy Coding !!!