# Cannot declare a void function before the main() in C

Tags: c, function, declaration

I'm a beginner in C language and in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58994523/are-there-advantages-of-declaring-functions-before-after-or-inside-main) I have asked about proper function declaration order in C. I was told that in standard C, it is necessary to declare functions before calling them.

But for the following example code I cannot declare the the function *times2p* before the main(). I tried to declare it as: **void times2(int in_data);** right before the main(), but I get errors. Here below is the example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 void times2p(int *in_data);
 void times2(int in_data);


int main()
{

    int y = 5;
    int s = times2(y);
    printf("%d\n", y);
    printf("%d\n", s);

    printf("-------------\n");

    int yp = 5;
    times2p(&yp);
    printf("%d\n", yp);

    return 0;
}
//Multiplies the input argument by two
void times2(int in_data){
    in_data = in_data*2;
}

void times2p(int *in_data){
    *in_data = *in_data*2;
}
```

How and where should the *times2p* function be declared in this case? If I don't declare the code still compiles without error but I was told that I have to declare the functions in C in my previous question.

Here is the error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in test1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\nnn\Documents\CodeBlocks\test1\main.c||In function 'main':|
C:\Users\nnn\Documents\CodeBlocks\test1\main.c|16|error: void value not ignored as it ought to be|
C:\Users\nnn\Documents\CodeBlocks\test1\main.c|13|warning: unused variable 'read_x' [-Wunused-variable]|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Is that because you should have declared it as `void times2p(int *in_data);` to match the function definition? A missing `*`.

Comment: And what were those errors?

Comment: You edited that the code "compiles without error" if you don't declare the function. There should be warnings though?

Comment: Sorry I edited my code sorry I wasn't expecting this quick comments. Now this is my code where I get error only if I do declare the functions before main.

Comment: Please show the exact errors you are getting.

Comment: Okay I added the errors I see after compilation

Comment: A void function doesn't return any value. This is the problem:
int s = times2(y);

Comment: The error messages you're showing refer to an unused variable named `read_x`. There is no such variable in your code, so it's obvious you're compiling something different than what you have posted here.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica Try it it gives error at: int s = times2(y);

Comment: Yes, that's where it produces the message `error: void value not ignored as it ought to be`, but there is no message produced about `unused variable read_x` because there isn't such a variable in the code in your question. ???

Comment: Yes that part was irrelevant to the error to make it clear I only posted the part with error. I was a bit hurrying people are so fast here.

Answer (score 4):

Your code in the current version of the question is incorrect, but not for the reason you're asking about.

There's nothing wrong with the `void` function declarations before `main`, and the compiler doesn't complain about them. The problem is that a `void` function doesn't return a value, and you're trying to call them as if they did:

```
int s = times2(y);
```

This would be correct only if `times2(y)` returned an `int` value (or a value of some type implicitly convertible to `int`).

Also, looking at the definition of the function:

```
void times2(int in_data){
    in_data = in_data*2;
}
```

The parameter `in_data` is a local variable within the function. Changing its value effectively does nothing.

Your `times2p` function looks OK, and it should work. If you want `times2()` to be useful, it needs to return a value:

```
int times2((int in_data) {
    return in_data * 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(The question has changed, so this answer may not be perfect anymore, sorry).

You need to declare at least the prototype of the functions before you use it. Like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//How should the function times2p be declared here?
void times2p(int *in_data);

int main()
{
    int y = 5;
    times2p(&y);
    printf("%d\n", y);

    return 0;
}

//Multiplies the input argument by two
void times2p(int *in_data){
    *in_data = *in_data*2;
}
```

Or declare the function itself, like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Multiplies the input argument by two
void times2p(int *in_data){
    *in_data = *in_data*2;
}

int main()
{
    int y = 5;
    times2p(&y);
    printf("%d\n", y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I edited my code sorry I wasnt expecting this quick answer. Can you compile my new code? I get errors.

Comment: To improve the answer please provide some explanation rather than just a code dump.

Comment: I added to the question it says error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Comment: I've answered up there @floppy380

Comment: But what I dont get is if I don't declare times2 at the beginning the code runs without error. It gives warnings but the times2 function returns value. In my code if you delete " void times2(int in_data);" declaration the code works. That is confusing.

Comment: @floppy380 it works because, by default, the compiler declares the functions missing as "int foo()", and it gets the last value on the stack as a return, but is not safe. Actually, it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @floppy380 if you want the function to return a value, you need to declare it explictly. PS. Choose the answer.

Comment: @EduardoFernandes: The question has been updated. Your answer does not address the code that's currently in the question. (One might argue that the update was inappropriate if it invalidated an existing answer.)

Comment: @EduardoFernandes In C99 and later, calling an undeclared function is not merely undefined behavior, it's a constraint violation. (C99 dropped the "implicit `int`" rule.)